# how to hide header redirect on address bar?

Tags: php

I do have a redirect from `search.php` to `get.php` using header command and then redirect back to `search.php` the whole process takes only around few seconds.

what I want is I want to hide this redirect on address bar. say this redirect must happened behind the screen. so all the time

the address line should show for example :- http://wwww.example.com/search

Comment: That would be against the principles of redirect then. Don't think it is possible.

Comment: so what will be a solution for this??

Comment: A very poor solution would be to use an iFrame.

Comment: You can use ajax instead of standard http requests. you will remain on the same page, and there's basically no limit to what you can do, even reload the full page contents if you want by rewriting the dom. If the process takes a few seconds, you can even display a nice waiting message with a fancy little animated gif.

Comment: you forgot to tell us why do you need that. I am sure such a redirect is unnecessary and there is an elegant solution

Comment: search.php will display result on whatever search terms. but if the same isnt available then it will call get.php to grab data. get.php will insert data in database and it will forwarded to search.php again and search.php will display the result.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible.

In order to hide your header-redirect, you’ll have to drop it and use a different technique. E.g. after you check for whatever and then set the header-redirect, do what you do in your `get.php` there instead of redirecting.